# Publishing a web page online developed with Java on Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, github

I have a simple webpage. Fetching some data from my local mysql database. I am able to run it on my localhost.

I have deployed it to my github account however page errors that "you must provide an index.html file" however I have the index.jsp rather than index.html.

My questions are

1- Is it mandatory to have an index.html page to publish a webpage online or it is the way of github works? Is there a workaround for github.

2- DB is in my local and It couldn't fetch the data from my local db when it is online. What should I change in my project in order to satisfy it.

Is there a suggestion for a reference document for my questions.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot publish projects with server-side logic/connections to gh-pages / github io. You'll need to get a host that allows you to publish JSP's, and you'll need to move your database to an actual hosted solution as well so that it is accessible to the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CollinD is right, that won't work on github. You could try https://www.openshift.com instead.